# How will Google handle indexing product URL from two stores where the inventory is shared

Tags: magento-1.9, indexing

How will Google handle indexing product URL from two stores where the inventory is shared, We are about to set you a second Magento site selling a subsection of our main inventory.
We expect to share the Inventory but are concerned about Google indexing.

Will Google have a problem with the same product under two different URS's
http://www.thewoolshop.ie/magento/index.php/haberdashery/buttons/novelty-buttons/15mm-rainbow-button-x-5-ref-71.html
http://www.buttonsforsale.com/magento/index.php/haberdashery/buttons/novelty-buttons/15mm-rainbow-button-x-5-ref-71.html

Answer (score 2):

If you're worried about the ranking in SER, then yes, there will be an impact and the higher your SEP, the harder you will be hit.

A different IP, different product descriptions, short descriptions, and URL after the base URL, will go a long way in helping to keep the rank you already have.

If you're using a different site to only appeal to local customers or from some other reason you don't need to be indexed, then block the bots from indexing the secondary site.

This is kind of, an opinion based answer. There's not really documentation from Google to say what it will or won't do, and every situation will be unique. Be cautious of spreading your content thin